# How do I properly run CAT6 less than standard 8" from power cables?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, nec, ethernet, network

I am trying to run CAT6 to a doorbell which is near 14-2 Romex triple gang box. It's on the other side of the wall about 6" from the 3 gang box on the other side of where the blue tape is marked.  I believe the NEC requirement is 8".

What is the best way to go about this?

shielded or unshielded? If shielded is needed, how do I properly ground the cable?

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of a NEC requirement.  I do hear a great deal of worry from networking people about crosstalk from power lines degrading the signal, and they claim distances like that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it is possible to induce a current in the UTP wire, so I believe there are distance requirements in the code book IF the UTP cable is not marked with a voltage rating. All the cat6 UTP I’ve worked with recently is rated for 600V so you can run it alongside mains wires.

Comment: @RibaldEddie that voltage rating is for the insulation on the cable and specifies what the highest voltage is which can come into direct contact with the cable safely. It doesn't have anything to do with induced current.

Comment: @brhans that’s what the electrical inspector said. I guess I shouldn’t assume he knows what he’s talking about then.

Comment: Well - if that's what he said, then no you shouldn't - because unfortunately he clearly doesn't. Inducing current in one wire requires a magnetic field - the magnetic field is produced by another wire nearby - the strength of the field depends on the current flowing through that wire - not the voltage between the 2 wires. You could have 10kV between the 2 wires, but if there's no current flowing there won't be any magnetic field and therefore no induced current. However if the insulation between the wires is not rated for that 10kV you'll have insulation breakdown and an arc jump between them.

Comment: @brhans well that makes sense then given what he said.

Comment: I believe NEC may in fact have something buried in it, and I believe it's 2"/50mm, not 8". There are also a bunch of people on the internet who are somehow convinced that a cable and data encoding scheme specifically designed to reject and cancel interference is terribly prone to it and they have far larger numbers, based on Fear Uncertainty & Doubt, and repeating a lot of FUD as certain knowledge.

Comment: There are exceptions based on cable insulation. Have a link. https://www.commscope.com/globalassets/digizuite/3164-power-separation-guidelines-tp-106296-en.pdf

Comment: @Ecnerwal, in the section titled, "2.0 Power Cables Rating: Va.c ≤ 415V and I ≤ 100A", top of page 5, it shows a chart which states (1x) power cable needs a Separation Distance of 0" for a 90m data cable. Am I reading this wrong, that doesnt seems right.

Comment: No you're not reading that wrong. Under normal circumstances data cables do not need to be separated from power cables. The insulation on both the power and data cables far exceeds the required amount to prevent any flashover between them. Also, following the NEC rules which mandate that a circuit's hot and neutral are never appreciably separated means that there's very little magnetic field produced which might induce currents in your data cable - and even then your data cable is a twisted pair which also mitigates any induced current (since it's induced equally in both wires of each pair).

Comment: @brhans that is great news. I thought I was misreading something when it stated zero separation between data and power less than 415V and 100A. I can continue with my installation, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you know which side of the stud bay the 14/2 is on, you can run the CAT 6 on the other side of the bay. That will provide about 14" of separation. When the CAT 6 has to cross to be near the 14/2, it will be crossing, not running parallel and shouldn't pick up too much interference.

UTP cable (Unshielded Twisted Pair) is designed so the twists in the cables resist cross-talk between the pairs, but also to reject external interference. Running parallel to 120v main power could overcome the cable's designed in resistance, but crossing the cable, as described above, shouldn't be a significant issue.

I *believe* that shielded CAT 6 cable has to be terminated with a shielded RJ45 jack that has metal on the outside which is connected to the shielding in the cable and is then grounded by the router. I'm not certain if the router has to be specifically designed to handle shielded cable, but I'd say there's a high probability. I just looked at a residential grade router I've got sitting around - some of the jacks have a metal strip on the inside, some are all plastic. The metal strip *might* be grounded. You'd have to look at the documentation for *your* router to know for sure.